# How do I access this item in a Scala HashMap?

Tags: java, scala, hashmap, tuples, treemap

I'm new to Scala and confused by this data:

```
result.accountDetail.outs.get("Total_Before_Tax").get
```

`result.accountDetail.outs` is a HashMap. `result.accountDetail.outs.get("Total_Before_Tax")` is an Option. `result.accountDetail.outs.get("Total_Before_Tax").get`  is another HashMap which, according to the IDE, has a single item:

[image]

How do I get a hold of this item? This returns `None`:

```
result.accountDetail.outs.get("Total_Before_Tax").get.get(Map(
  "bill_category" -> "Total_Before_Tax",
  "bill_presentation_category" -> "audit",
  "bill_super_category" -> "audit_charge"
))
```

I also tried using a `mutable.HashMap` and a `mutable.TreeMap` as the key but it had the same result.

I also tried using `.find` and `.equals` like so:

```
result.accountDetail.outs.get("Total_Before_Tax").get.find(_._1.equals(mutable.TreeMap(
  "bill_category" -> "Total_Before_Tax",
  "bill_presentation_category" -> "audit",
  "bill_super_category" -> "audit_charge"
)))
```

Comment: You should not use Maps as keys. This makes your code hard to follow and prone to errors for no benefit. Using `.get(Map(...))` should work, because as long as the `Map` has the same contents, it will generate the same hashcode. If you get `None` then that means your Map key differs from yours. It can generate a totally different hashcode for as much as an uppercase letter, space, or any whitespace in fact, especially if you made a typo somewhere in those strings.

Comment: Have you tried an immutable `TreeMap` ?

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip thanks for the advice, but this is inherited code. I did try immutable `TreeMap`. I just realized that TreeMap is a java.util.TreeMap, which is probably the issue.

Comment: You should have received a type mismatch. That definitely is the issue then. Scala TreeMap and Java util.TreeMap are 2 different collections.

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip who knows what implicits are in scope...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the TreeMap was an instance of `java.util.TreeMap`. The solution was to use `.asJava`:

```
result.accountDetail.outs.get("Total_Before_Tax").get.get(Map(
  "bill_category" -> "Total_Before_Tax",
  "bill_presentation_category" -> "audit",
  "bill_super_category" -> "audit_charge"
).asJava)
```